# Angular JS disabled/enable submit button for edit form onchange

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I am making an app where I have an edit form. I have the save button start disabled, then when something is typed into the form, the button is enabled (did this using $dirty).

The issue is once the form is "saved" (which is really submitting the info to the database) the button does not go back to being disabled.

```
<button ng-click="saveThis(item)" ng-disabled="!formy_edit.$dirty" id="save_button">Save</button>
```

I tried disabling it on the submit of the form like this:

```
 <button ng-click="saveThis(item)" ng-disabled="!formy_edit.$dirty || formy_edit.$submitted">Save</button>
```

But then the feature to disable-enable only works 1 time since the form is already submitted of course.

Could use some help/guidance, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of $dirty and $submitted, try this out:

`ng-disabled="!(!!user.name && !!user.email)"`

Check out this example : https://plnkr.co/edit/59mvzN2RwNmb1yDOCskv?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You shoud set form pristine after submitted . Try this :

```
 $scope.saveThis= function(item,form) { //name of form
  $http.post('..').then(function(){
form.$setPristine();   
})
}
```